# Why is my unit test case missing the if statements to cover in python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have written a test case for a function. The function basically returns an output whose content type is a text/csv. Upon running the command `python3 -m pytest --cov-report term-missing --cov=projfolder/` I get the lines which are being missed and those are all in the if statements.
My understanding of the issue is that the testcase passes but misses the statements which are in the if loop. Look at this example
func.py

```
@process_bp.route("/getListCSV")
def get_list_csv():

    companies_flask_list = db.session.query(Companies, LeadsStatus).join(LeadsStatus,
                                                                         Companies.id == LeadsStatus.company_id)

    industry_sele = "All"
    country_sele = "UK"
    size_sele = "All"

    filters = {'open': True, 'assign': True, 'closed': True}

    status_list = ['open', 'allocated', 'converted', 'not converted']

    if 'industry' in request.form:
        industry_sele = request.form['industry']
        country_sele = request.form['country']
        size_sele = request.form['size']

        if not request.form.get('open'):
            filters['open'] = False
            if 'open' in status_list:
                status_list.remove('open')
        if not request.form.get('assign'):
            filters['assign'] = False
            if 'allocated' in status_list:
                status_list.remove('allocated')
        if not request.form.get('closed'):
            filters['closed'] = False
            if 'converted' in status_list:
                status_list.remove('converted')
            if 'not converted' in status_list:
                status_list.remove('not converted')

    if 'industry' in request.args:
        industry_sele = request.args.get('industry')
        country_sele = request.args.get('country')
        size_sele = request.args.get('size')

        if request.args.get('open') == 'False':
            filters['open'] = False
            if 'open' in status_list:
                status_list.remove('open')

        if request.args.get('assign') == 'False':
            filters['assign'] = False

            if 'allocated' in status_list:
                status_list.remove('allocated')

        if request.args.get('closed') == 'False':
            filters['closed'] = False
            if 'converted' in status_list:
                status_list.remove('converted')
            if 'not converted' in status_list:
                status_list.remove('not converted')
```

All these lines (which are inside each if statements are missing). Look at my way of unit testing this function. test_func.py

```
    def test_get_list_csv_manager(self):
        with self.client.session_transaction() as session:
            session['role'] = 'manager'
            session['id'] = 2
        res = self.client.get("/getListCSV", follow_redirects=True)
        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 200)
```

How should I write the testcase so that these if statements would be covered in these? I am stuck like a bee on this issue since 5days and I have no help or luck whatsoever.

**EDIT**: Here is how I tried it the other way around.

```
    def test_get_list_csv_form_requests(self):
        with self.client.session_transaction() as session:
            session['role'] = 'manager'
            session['id'] = 2

            mock_request_data = {
                'industry_sele': 'Compliance',
                'country_sele': 'UK',
                'size_sele': '5000'
            }
        res = self.client.get("/getListCSV", data=json.dumps(mock_request_data),follow_redirects=True)
        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 200)
```

Comment: The problem is that, when the unit test case invokes your function under test, it checks whether the inputs given to the function are able to cover all the parts of the code or not. of course at a time either if or else will be covered, so in order to cover the uncovered code just change the inputs to the function so that it covers the rest of the code (which is not covered by first input) with these inputs.

Comment: @MaheshAnakali thank you for the quick reply. By saying 'just change the inputs to the function..' do you mean that in the session transaction function I should include the parts which haven't been covered yet? Because I have tried giving it that way but that didn't change anything.

Comment: To make it more clear, can you post the how the request content looks like?

Comment: @MaheshAnakali Yes you can check it,I have edited my question.

Comment: you are almost there, did you checked the coverage after this?

Comment: @MaheshAnakali yes there was no change in the coverage...What more is to be done?

Comment: in mock_request_data rename keys (remove '_sele' it should be same as how you have used in your function.

Comment: @MaheshAnakali removed _sele still there is no change in the coverage and the lines are being missed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Found an answer to this question of mine.
What worked for me was this piece of code.

```
    def test_request_form_csv(self):
        with self.client.session_transaction() as session:
            session['role'] = 'manager'
            session['id'] = 2
        r = self.client.get('/getListCSV', data={'industry': 'All', 'country': 'UK', 'size': 'All'})
        self.assertEqual(r.status_code, 200)
```